# pyecharts in python 3.6 (anaconda3) Jupyter Notebook throws error: ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

What I want to accomplish:
execute import pyecharts statement within Jupyter Notebook.

What is the environment:

Anaconda3 installed on Windows 10 - 64 bit Version
pyecharts installed via pip (pip install pyecharts)
-> this worked as pip list shows that pyecharts 0.5.6 is installed

jupyter notebook works, for example import pandas works fine

What happens:

after issuing the command from pyecharts import xxx(for example Bar) within the jupyter notebook, the following error message appears:

```
...
---> 10 from pyecharts.charts.effectscatter import EffectScatter
...
----> 3 from pyecharts.charts.scatter import Scatter
...
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

Thanks in advance for any helpful answer!